# Chrome Extension App losing Local Storage once a while

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have a Chrome Extension that uses Local Storage.
I set it using:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({key: 'mymenu', listarray: listarray}, function() {});
```

and get it using:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['key', 'listarray'], function(result) {
```

Overall it works, even after restarts. But once in a while (approx. every few days to a week) the local storage is gone. It is possible to re-do the setting and it works again for another few days to a week.

What could be the reason the extension keep losing the local storage?

Comment: You're using `Sync Storage`, not `Local Storage`. The behavior seems like a bug in the browser, probably a sync collision. Or maybe you're running some cleaner utility like CCleaner.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tips. I will change it to Local Storage to see if it make any difference. I am not using CCleaner. But running on my company laptop, perhaps there is some app in the image I am not aware of. Thanks again.

Comment: Can confirm that I also have problems with various extensions losing stored settings and it also happens at unpredictable times.